# PowerShellでTwitterのツイートを取得すると140文字しか取得できない

Tags: twitter, powershell

「MyTwitter」というAPIを使用して特定ユーザーのツイート情報を取得しようとしています。英語のツイートでは最大280文字ですが、140文字までしか取得できません。ツイートの本文をすべて取得することはできますか？
現在、実行しているコードは以下です。

```
#アプリケーション情報、トークン情報
$ApiKey = "**************"
$ApiSecret = "**************"
$AccessToken = "**************"
$AccessTokenSecret = "**************"

New-MyTwitterConfiguration -ApiKey $ApiKey -ApiSecret $ApiSecret -AccessToken $AccessToken -AccessTokenSecret $AccessTokenSecret
Get-TweetTimeline -Username '****' -IncludeRetweets false
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tweetオブジェクト](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object)の`text`プロパティは歴史的に140文字に丸められています。[Extended Tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json#extendedtweet)を見るとわかりますが、`extended_tweet`プロパティの`full_text`に280文字まで収められています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
extended_tweetプロパティのfull_textで全てのツイート情報が取得できました。